# Can I inflate a context menu from within a custom class (not an Activity Class)?

Tags: java, android, contextmenu

I am writing an application in which it is my desire to populate a gridview with objects of my own making. The code for my custom object is below. I want my object to, among other things, inflate a context menu.

My trouble is that I don't seem to be able to use getMenuInflater() method outside of an Activity class. . . in an attempt to get around this restriction, I pass my main activity into the object. While this does let me call the getMenuInflater() method, I still don't see a menu when I run the code.

Any help is appreciated!

I do know that I could just inflate the menu directly from the Activity class. But, if possible I would like to keep all of this functionality inside of the custom object.

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimalKind extends ImageView implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener{

    private int         m_imageId, m_soundId;
    private Context     m_ctx;
    private Activity    m_activity;


    public AnimalKind(Context ctx, int imageId, int soundId, Activity act) {
        super(ctx);

        m_imageId   = imageId;
        m_activity  = act;
        m_ctx       = ctx;
        super.setImageResource(imageId);
        super.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        super.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        super.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        super.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        super.setOnClickListener(this);
        super.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        m_activity.registerForContextMenu(this); 
      }


    @Override
    protected void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = m_activity.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.animal_kind_menu, menu);

    }


    //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do stuff
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //Do stuff
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me: Instead of trying to inflate a menu from XML, I just created the menu items directly from the java:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {   

        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Share Animal Sound");
        menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Change Picture");
        menu.add(1, 3, 3, "Change Sound");

        menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); 
        menu.getItem(1).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); 
        menu.getItem(2).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); 
    }
```